# How to upload local files to empty GitHub Repository Created By A Client

Tags: git, github

My client has provided me with an empty GitHub Repository, I need to upload my local files to this repository, the problem is I don't see a "Clone" option in the GitHub page, is it because the repository is empty, I read that repositories needs to be initialized first with at least the ReadMe file or is it because I don't have permission to clone the repository because the client doesn't have my email/GitHub id or is it both?

PS: I have worked on couple of Git projects so I'm familiar with the command lines but I have never created a new repository. I have also  installed GitHub Desktop on Mac and plan to use it instead of the command line option.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Initiate a git repository on your local

```
git init
```

Add remote url to git

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Make you commits and push to remote

```
git push origin master
```

More explanation [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: Thanks Shashwat. So the "Clone" option is not visible on the page because there are no files in the repository? or is it because I don't have permission?

Comment: Because of no files in repository. If you can see repo on github, then you can always clone it. No read permissions are required.

Comment: But I probably would need permission to commit the files to repository, right? The client wants me to upload my local files to this empty repository.

Comment: Yes, you'll need the owner of repo to provide you write permissions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Just one more question, I have GitHub Desktop installed and when I go to File > Clone Repository, the pop up message shows that I don't have any repositories to clone, is it because I don't have permission to this particular repository? If the client gives me read/write access to the repository, will this Clone Repository link display this client's empty repository?

Comment: I am not aware of any Github client. For cloning no permission is required but how does a desktop client know which repository to clone. There are thousands of repos that you can clone. So desktop client should not be listing repository and instead should be asking url or name of the repository.

Comment: This is GitHub's official desktop app (https://desktop.github.com/). I assumed that since I have signed in into the desktop app using my GitHub ID, the app would detect the repositories I have permission to and list it in clone option but it's not important, you already answered my main queries. I will go through your answer and the link you provided and if it works I will accept your answer. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Since October 2018, you don't even need anymore to clone, add, commit and push to an empty GitHub repository: you can do so directly from the GitHub Web interface.

See "[Create and upload files to empty repos](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-10-30-create-upload-files-empty-repos/)":

> Now when you create an empty repository, you will be presented with the ability to create files using GitHub’s online code editor or upload files directly from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

How to upload local files to empty GitHub Repository

```bash
git init
git add .
git commit -m "<COMMIT-MESSAGE>"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin "<REMOTE-URL>"
git push -u origin main
```